# Can obj.GetType().IsInterface be true?

Tags: c#, reflection

While doing something almost completely irrelevant, a question popped into my head:

**Can an expression of the form `obj.GetType().IsInterface` ever be true in a codebase consisting exclusively of C# code?**

I suspect the answer is no, because:

- `GetType()` will always return the runtime type.
- The runtime type for concrete types matches the invoked constructor. Thus, it is never an interface, because interfaces don't have constructors.
- Anonymous types cannot implement an interface (and if they did, they'd still have their anonymous class type).
- Instances of internal classes of other assemblies implementing public interfaces will still have the class as the runtime type.
- [Using `[ComImport, CoClass(typeof(MyClass))]` on an interface](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2009/08/who-says-you-cant-instantiate-interface.html) makes it look like you can instantiate it, but the constructor call actually instantiates the referenced class.

I can't think of any other case. Am I missing something, or is my guess correct?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Can an expression of the form `obj.GetType().IsInterface` ever be true in a codebase consisting exclusively of C# code?

Yes - but probably not the way you were thinking of:

```
using System;

public class EvilClass
{
    public new Type GetType()
    {
        return typeof(IDisposable);
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        EvilClass obj = new EvilClass();
        Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType().IsInterface); // True
    }
}
```

Slightly similarly, I believe you could create a subclass of [`RealProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy(v=vs.110).aspx) which would intercept the call and return an interface type.

If you mean "will the return value of the `GetType()` method declared in `object` ever be an interface type" - in that case I suspect the answer is no.

Comment: Devious. I guess that's worth two or three badges. :)

Comment: +1 for proving it can be done, but there are some things best not taught. If I *ever* have to fix code that did this. I'm going to come find you @Jon. Just joking. :)

Comment: For COM classes, `new ISomeComInterface()` is merely a compiler trick: it translates it into something else, either `new SomeComClass()` or `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(SomeComGuid))`. Either way, the runtime will never see an interface being created, so I don't think that can be used to get `GetType()` to return an interface.

Comment: @hvd: Yup, that's my conclusion too. Will delete the bit about COM.